# Application of parallel transport in computer graphics and mesh processing

Tags: mesh, vectors

Does anyone know what applications has the computation of a parallel transport on a mesh?

I'm talking about methods such as [this one](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/VectorHeatMethod/paper.pdf)

Comment: There's a whole section on applications in the paper.

Comment: I was talking about something more in layman terms. I wouldn't exactly count logarithmic map as something a layman can understand, sure you can compute it, but what can you do with it?

Comment: Too many things. An excerpt from the paper: ```As observed by Schmidt et al. [2006], the logarithmic
map (referred to there as the exponential map) is useful for a large
number of tasks in geometry processing, such as interactive shape
editing [Schmidt and Singh 2010] and texture decaling (Fig. 17).```
My best advice is that you read the paper and follow the references. I am not exactly sure what you're looking for specifically. If you have a specific application in mind do mention it.

Comment: Augmented Reality.

Comment: Then using the log map to virtually place decals onto actual objects should be one application. Another application has to do with the ordered intrinsic landmark section - namely keeping track of various landmarks (see Fig. 25).

Comment: Can you mention in this context why keeping track of the landmarks might be useful?

Comment: There are too many ways in which this is useful. But for example you may want to transfer the movement of a person as an animation for some 3d model - basically animation transfer. To transfer the animation, you would need landmarks corresponding to the "bones" of your 3d model - for instance arms, legs etc.